# Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset

Tags: android, flutter, csv, android-studio

I am trying to pick a csv file from a local path and convert its contents to a list of a model class I created. It works fine sometimes after a hot restart.

```
get _localFilePath async{
    final path = await checkPathForFile();
    csvToList('$path/car_ownsers_data.csv');
}


csvToList(String path) async{
  final myData = await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  List<List<dynamic>> csvList = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
  for(int i=1; i<csvList.length; i++){
    carOwnersList.add(
      CarOwner(
        id: csvList[i][0],
        firstName: csvList[i][1],
        lastName:csvList[i][2],
        email: csvList[i][3],
        country: csvList[i][4],
        carModel: csvList[i][5],
        carModelYear: csvList[i][6],
        carColor: csvList[i][7],
        gender: csvList[i][8],
        jobTitle: csvList[i][9],
        bio: csvList[i][10],
      )
    );
  }
  print(carOwnersList.length);
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: priscilla_abhulimen
description: Ehealth4Everyone Freelance Developer Assessment

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  dio: ^3.0.10
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  flutter_downloader: ^1.5.2
  csv: ^4.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
   - assets/images/
```

That is my code and this is the error I get when it should be running:

```
E/flutter (10131): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.priscilla_abhulimen/files/ehealth/car_ownsers_data.csv
E/flutter (10131): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (10131): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10131): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:67:33)
E/flutter (10131): #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:56)
E/flutter (10131): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:293:23)
E/flutter (10131): #4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:27)
E/flutter (10131): #5      csvToList (package:priscilla_abhulimen/services/car_owner_services.dart:11:35)
E/flutter (10131): #6      _FilterItemState._localFilePath (package:priscilla_abhulimen/pages/filter_page.dart:168:5)
E/flutter (10131): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10131): #7      _FilterItemState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:priscilla_abhulimen/pages/filter_page.dart:213:13)
E/flutter (10131): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (10131): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (10131): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (10131): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (10131): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (10131): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
E/flutter (10131): #14     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (10131): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (10131): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (10131): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (10131): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (10131): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (10131): #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (10131): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (10131): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (10131): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (10131): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

I saw something about how rootbundle should not be used to access such files but I don't understand it. Could someone give me an explanation?

Comment: please post your code structure and pubspec.yaml file

Comment: I don't know what you mean by code structure but my pubspec file has been added.

Comment: Where is the `car_ownsers_data.csv` located ? Did you tell the `Pubsec.yaml` where the `car_ownsers_data.csv` located is ?

Comment: the file is located on the android device, it gets downloaded when the app is first opened. I got external storage directory and saved it in a folder I created there.

Comment: add your csv file to your assets, then it will work, if you are getting the data from user, then store them in the phone and save your path in a sql db and access it

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying all day